# How to make a vba code in a form that show/hides query columns? ( MS- Access)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am extremely new to working with Access and am having trouble with writing VBA code that will would do something like this:

```
Private Sub YesNoShowHide ()

        If DateTested_checkbox = 'yes'
            Then show 'DateTested' column in 'search query' query
        Else DateTested_checkbox = 'no'
            Then hide 'DateTested' column in 'search query' query 
End Sub
```

I have a database that has a form that will perform a "custom search" by typing keywords into the text boxes and hitting search it will but the keywords into the query. I have many fields and would like to make a option that would show or hide the columns in the query based off the check boxes in the form.

Any help at all or suggestions would be appreciated

Form and Query Picture:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733646/hide-a-column-programmatically-in-ms-access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show and hide query columns by accessing them using the `QueryDefs.Fields.Properties` collection.

You can use it in the following way:

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("search query").Fields("DateTested").Properties("ColumnHidden") = True
```

Note that this will not change an opened query until it's refreshed, and will permanently alter the query. You can do the following if you want to prevent modifying the query permanently:

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("search query").Fields("DateTested").Properties("ColumnHidden") = True
DoCmd.OpenQuery "search query"
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("search query").Fields("DateTested").Properties("ColumnHidden") = False
```

Comment: I got it to work using the code I added in my question update but It only works when I go step-by-step in the debug "step into" window While I have the query open. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: tag @ErikVonAsmuth

Comment: What exactly isn't working when you're testing it? Is it throwing an error, or just not hiding the column?

Comment: Oh, and remove the `Forms!search.` from your if statement, if you're triggering it from the form, since that's redundant.

Comment: There aren't any errors, it just does not perform the task and nothing changes.

Comment: Can you add a message box to both the if and the else statement, to confirm the correct one triggers?

Comment: I think I can, but I know that they are triggering because it will show or hide the column in the query correct?  (BUT it only does this when I run it in the debugging step by step mode)

Comment: Yes, but this is just basic debugging. You want to know if the If statement doesn't trigger correctly, or if the `CurrentDb.QueryDefs("search query").Fields("DateTested").Properties("ColumnHidden") = True` doesn't hide it because of reasons.

Comment: Okay, I will try that. (Sorry I'm still really new to vba)

Comment: I figured out what I did wrong. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `ColumnHidden` and `CheckBox.Value` properties.  Your example sub would look like this:

```
Private Sub YesNoShowHide()

        If Forms!Search_form.DateTested_checkbox.Value = True Then
            Forms!Search_form.DateTested.ColumnHidden = False
        Else
            Forms!Search_form.DateTested.ColumnHidden = True
        End If

End Sub
```

The `.Value` for a checkbox object is `True` when it's checked and `False` when it's not.  Replace `Search_form` with the name of your form.