# Selecting columns for display based on user criterion in MSAccess

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have an access table with columns

Account Id, account description, GL Code, year, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec. The months columns holds the amount.

I want if user selects Jan on Form than Account Id, account description, Gl code,year and Jan gets displayed. Similarly if user selects Feb than Account Id account description, gl code, year and Feb gets displayed. Similarly for other months.

Have no idea on how to do this. To my knowledge we can filter rows but not the columns.

Please suggest if any possible solution. Please note that I cannot change the database design as the data is getting downloaded from ERP package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a vba code in a form that show/hides query columns? ( MS- Access)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573460/how-to-make-a-vba-code-in-a-form-that-show-hides-query-columns-ms-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query where you set the SQL dynamically:

```
Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
Dim SQL As String
Dim MonthName As String

MonthName = "Feb"  ' Month to search.

Set qd = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("YourQuery")
SQL = "Select [GL Code], [year], [" & MonthName & "] As Amount From YourTable"
qd.SQL = SQL
```

Now, open the query or open a recordset using the query as source.

**SQL only**:

```
Select 
    [GL Code], 
    [year], 
    IIf(MonthName = 'Jan', [Jan],
    IIf(MonthName = 'Feb', [Feb],
    IIf(MonthName = 'Mar', [Mar],
    IIf(MonthName = 'Apr', [Apr],
    IIf(MonthName = 'May', [May],
    IIf(MonthName = 'Jun', [Jun],
    IIf(MonthName = 'Jul', [Jul],
    IIf(MonthName = 'Aug', [Aug],
    IIf(MonthName = 'Sep', [Sep],
    IIf(MonthName = 'Oct', [Oct],
    IIf(MonthName = 'Nov', [Nov],
    IIf(MonthName = 'Dec', [Dec])))))))))))) As Amount
From 
    YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to do only through SQL query without using VBA

Comment: It seems that this may work. I will try. If I replace monthname with reference to the text box on the form where user will select month than the result will be correct. Thanks.

Comment: You could use `switch` instead of nesting 12 `IIF`s.This looks needlesly complex, unless you really like parentheses.